# Vi-Vim like control keybindings for Windows

Tags: windows, browser, vim, windows-explorer, vi

I've been using gVim for a while and love the interface. I'm in love with my keyboard-fu skillz.

I was wondering if there was any application that would extend its functionality to all parts of Windows 7? At least some basic functionality.

I'd like to be able to control Explorer, a browser, etc.

I just want to stop using my bloody mouse. It's no fun.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [TouchCursor](http://touchcursor.sourceforge.net/)? It's a free program that allows you to remap your keys so that instead of using the arroy keys, you use a combination of keys to get the arrow key functionality.

No need to use the mouse since you will not be leaving your hands in the "home keys".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a generic way of doing it across all of Windows, but I've collected lots of different applications that can be controlled with vi keyboard commands at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826208/making-vim-ubiquitous

Comment: Your link is no longer working :/

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox / Thunderbird you can use http://dactyl.sourceforge.net/pentadactyl/index
and http://dactyl.sourceforge.net/teledactyl

Comment: I also like Vimium for the google chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to reply on such an old thread. Like Ramsus Larsen mentioned, there's Vimium for chrome which is fantastic.

Your question was in relation to windows explorer browsers. You could use `AutoHotKey` to bind the arrows to `hjkl` when you are in explorer. Note that you would be losing the functionality to instantly go to a file by pressing `hjkl` if it begins with that.